# Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0]

Tags: android, google-play-services

Error:(51) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0] on project ':app'.

How to fix this error?

Please have a look at build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XYZ"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 13
        versionName "3.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    complie 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, is `complie()` in any of your build files? What about the error message is confusing?

Comment: I have updated build.gradle and come up with this error , How to fix it

Comment: Sorry let me post it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
complie 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
```

The error is basically saying that gradle does not know what `complie` is.

Comment: I am having lots of pressure , I have built app in 1 month from scratch , I can feel now what I am , I lost all my logical ability I feel :(

Comment: I found that I can't force myself to work for hours without a break, and that typos and small coding mistakes tend to happen a lot more when I'm too tired to work, which  generates more work down the line. Taking breaks is important for you to code in the best mental condition, so you can have the focus you need when working. Your logical abilities will come back shortly, I'm sure ;)

Comment: @2Dee. Thanks for the appreciation , but at my workplace situation is really different , fast, fast fast

Comment: Incredible! After many many hours of fighting against this problem, just when I was quitting the search and started writing my question's title I clicked on this question which has a similar title.... When i read this answer i thought "Impossible"... run to my graddle code... and I made the same typo... haha